# Delegate GoogleMap managment Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-fragments, android-activity

i was trying to delegate the managent of google Map on my android project to an other component. (I dont know whitch one right now). I need this cuz, my "Map class" is a little heavy, so i tried this methid, any suggest?

Main

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMapsBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        BlankFragment(supportFragmentManager)

    }
}
```

Other compont for MapManagment

```
class BlankFragment(supportFragmentManager: FragmentManager) : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

    init {
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap
        Log.d("here","HERE")
        val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
    }
}
```